# Insert data into a table dynamic way

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I was wondering if there is a way to insert data into a table just like this.

Suppose that we have this data:

```
array = ["hola", "que", "tal", ""]
array2 = ["saludos", "amigos", "", ""]
array3 = ["hi", "friends", "", "", "", "Bye"]
```

I want insert this through SP into a table in Sql Server

The structure of the table could be like this:

```
field1 | field2 | field3 | field 4 | field 5 | field6 | ...... | fieldn
```

How can I insert that data into this table, keeping in mind that the number of fields is dynamic, this changes in every array.

In advance thanks for any suggestion and help.

Comment: the table should be a certain column in a database or are you trying to save that data into temp table. give me more clarity. Array list you can pass string format and then split it in proc

Comment: @PrashantBamania Thanks for you soon answer, well this is a table into my database, all fields are varchar. The idea is if i try to insert x fields get insert those ones in the first columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a max number of columns/positions, there is no need to go dynamc

I should add, if your source strings are in a table, this is easily migrated into a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @S='["hi","friends","","","","Bye"]'


Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') 
      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') 
      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
 From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(replace(replace(replace(@S,'"]',''),'["',''),'"',''),',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A
```

**Returns**

```
Pos1    Pos2    Pos3    Pos4    Pos5    Pos6    Pos7    Pos8
hi      friends                         Bye     NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer John, but if i send only 4 fields/Pos, how is the behaviour of this. Continue working?

Comment: @AndresClavijo The remaining would be NULL vaules

Comment: Ok, let me try and ill comment you the advance. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndresClavijo Added a little tweak so [ ]'s could exist within the values